Simple proof that convex polytope is regular iff its facets and vertex figures are regular
The textbook definition of a regular convex polytope (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) is a convex polytope whose symmetry group acts transitively on its flags. Or, more concretely: for any pair of flags there exists a Euclidean transformation (i.e. a distance-preserving linear map) that maps the first flag to the second flag and the polytope to itself.
Main question: In several sources I have seen the claim that a polytope is regular iff its facets are all regular and congruent to one another and all its vertex figures are all regular and congruent to one another. I was, however, unable to find a sufficiently simple proof of this and wonder if anyone can point me to an accessible presentation.
Addendum:
There are also some tricky points here that "vertex figure" can mean many different things. In my context of regular convex polytopes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ it seems to me that it is easiest to define the vertex figure of a vertex $v$ of a polytope as the convex hull of all other vertices that share an edge with $v$. Some people also take the midpoint of the adjacent edges, but I don't see the advantage. The tricky bit is that if the polytope isn't regular then the adjacent vertices are, generally, not even regular. So I guess the statement above should be read as "the vertex figures exist and are all congruent and regular".

The Szilassi polyhedron (see the "Related" list) is a counter-example in the abstract case. All vertex-edge pairs are equivalent, and all vertex-face pairs are equivalent, and all edge-face pairs are equivalent, but not all vertex-edge-face triples are equivalent. In the convex case, I have nothing.

Here's an approach that feels intuitive to me, although my presentation here will be a bit hand-wavy.
First, a lemma:

Let $n\ge2$. Given a choice of a convex regular $(n-1)$-polytope $F$ and an angle $\theta<\pi$, there is at most one polytope (up to similarity) whose facets are all congruent to $F$ and whose adjacent facets are all at a "dihedral angle" (angle between normal vectors) of $\theta$. Furthermore, if such a polytope exists, it is regular.

Proof: Lay down your first two facets at angle $\theta$ to one another wherever you like - there's only one choice up to similarity, because your facets are flag-transitive, so there's only one way to glue them along an $(n-2)$-face.
For each subsequent facet $F_0$ you "glue" on, pick any existing facet $F_1$ and an open $(n-2)$-face to attach to - $F_1$ will have at least one neighbor already in your construction, which tells you the direction in which to "fold" $F_0$ relative to $F_1$, so it'll force the position at which you must glue $F_0$ along the $(n-2)$-face. As you keep adding facets, you'll either close up into a regular polytope in finite time or get a self-intersecting mess. But your choices at every step were completely forced up to the initial orientation and scaling of your first two facets, so there can only have been at most one way to build this thing.
But if there's only one way to build this polytope from two facets joined at the proper angle, then it must look the same when viewed from the perspective of any two adjacent facets in this construction, so its symmetry group is transitive on ordered pairs of facets. Since your facets were regular polytopes, this gives you full flag-transitivity of the resulting polytope.

Now to show your desired equivalence: it's easy to see that flag-transitivity implies the other condition, so we just want to show that congruent facets and congruent regular vertex figures imply flag-transitivity. This is straightforward to verify for dimensions $1$ and $2$.
Now suppose $n\ge 3$, so we need at least three facets to a vertex. Consider a facet $F_0$ and a vertex $v_0$ on it, and take $F_1$ and $F_2$ to be two facets sharing an $(n-2)$-facet with $F_0$ and containing $v$. (In other words, we're considering how to attach two faces to $F_0$ which share the same vertex with it.)
Since your polytope's vertex figures are congruent and $(n-1)$-regular, their duals will be as well, so the equal edge lengths of the duals will correspond to equal dihedral angles between your facets. But what that constant dihedral angle is equal to is also forced: if we know that facet $A$ is adjacent to facets $B$ and $C$, all three of which share vertex $v$, then the geometry of $v$'s vertex figure forces the ratio between the $BC$ dihedral angle and te $AB$ or $AC$ dihedral angle. (For example, if we try to build something out of equilateral triangles with a pentagonal vertex figure, we know that in the dual vertex figure edge $BC$ has to be $1.618\ldots$ times longer than edge $AB$ and edge $AC$. Although in general this ratio will depend on the combinatorial relationship between $A,B,$ and $C$.) Since the $BC$ dihedral angle varies continuously as we adjust $\theta$, there can be at most one valid choice of $\theta$.

To get a bit more concrete, the way the above argument cashes out for building the Platonic solids looks like:

Suppose our facets are all triangles.

If we have a triangular vertex figure, we have to bend $AB$ and $AC$ so much that $BC$ is the same angle. Is $10$ degrees enough, no, is $20$ degrees, no, let's see, looks like we need about $70.5^\circ$. That folds up and is consistent, check.
If we have a square vertex figure, we don't need as much bending, how far do we need to go until $BC$ is $\sqrt{2}$ times as long in the dual vertex figure? Looks like we need about $109.47^\circ$. That folds up consistently, check.
If we have a pentagonal vertex figure, we don't need much folding to get a $1.618$ ratio, just a $138.19^\circ$ dihedral angle will do.
If we have a hexagonal vertex figure, we need... actually, we're at the target ratio with no folding at all! Seems like this polytope would want us to extend a flat plane forever, which wouldn't ever fold up into a convex polytope.
If we have a $\ge 7$-gon vertex figure, we'd be too far gone even with no folding.

Suppose our faces are squares.

Triangular vertex figure needs a dihedral angle of $90^\circ$, looks like that folds up, check.
Square vertex figure uses exactly zero folding, not convex.
Pentagonal or higher vertex figure can't be done, even locally.

Suppose our faces are pentagons.

Triangular vertex figure needs a dihedral angle of $116.565^\circ$, that folds up consistently, check.
Square vertex figure is already too much.

Suppose our faces are hexagons.

Triangular vertex figure already requires zero folding, not convex.

Suppose our faces are $\ge7$-gons.

Even triangular vertex figures are already too much.


Similar reasoning gets you from $3$ to $4$ and so on (and in fact the reasoning is easier since you only have finitely many combinations to check, although you need a bit more care in thinking about which vertex figures make sense to combine with which faces - some pairings don't make combinatorial sense).

And your argument at the end of the first section is not sufficient to guarantee flag-transitivity. The abstract Szilassi polyhedron has regular hexagonal faces, and the automorphism group is transitive on ordered pairs of adjacent faces (equivalently, face-edge pairs), but not transitive on flags.

@mr_e_man: apologies for the errors, should be fixed now! The argument in the first section doesn't work on the Szilassi polyhedron, because it's about a very geometric property (the angles between the hyperplanes defining each face) that doesn't correspond to anything meaningful for an abstract polyhedron.

But you use that geometric property only to conclude that any pair of adjacent facets is equivalent to any other pair. Beyond that, the argument looks abstract to me.
